# Maven custom/multiple web.xml

Tags: maven, netbeans, web-inf

I decided to customize the web.xml due to the fact application will be deployed in multiple urls (internal/external facing). I have a custom-resources folder and decided to put the custom web.xml in there.

However I can't manage to put it in the WEB-INF folder. I have created two resources one with inclusion and one with exclusion of web.xml. I have tried putting ${project.build.directory}/WEB-INF or WEB-INF or ..

I am on netbeans 8. It uses Maven 3. I am not sure if netbeans is tweaking things under the cover.

```
 <resource>
   <directory>custom-resources/dev</directory>
   <includes>
     <include>**/web.xml</include>
   </includes>
   <targetPath>..</targetPath>
 </resource>
```

Comment: Please be more specific, what type(s) of resources are we saying here, are they used as static content served on the frontend or just be read by the backend? I also need to clarify that this context, when deployed, will be used both from LAN/WAN users, is this correct?

Comment: I need to customize web.xml. I wanted to customize web.xml based on development versus production due to the jsf context params. I already have a folder called custom-resources which contain property files, log4j and such. I wanted to place the web.xml in that so I can pull based on profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get this done since automatically all the custom resources are copied to WEB-INF/classes. Decided to use the copy-resources plugin. The process is [explained here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) . If anyone has a different solution, please post it.